# NSwag AspNetCore camel case generation settings

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

Since the newest version of the Swagger this code (because of GeneratorSettings) is now obsolete:

```
 app.UseSwaggerUi(typeof(Startup).GetTypeInfo().Assembly, settings =>
        {
            settings.GeneratorSettings.DefaultPropertyNameHandling =
                PropertyNameHandling.CamelCase;
        });
```

Instead, we should use:

```
services.AddSwaggerDocument(cfg =>
        {
           ...
        });
```

However, I have no idea where to set-up the camel case thing now. Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting with the main NSwag developer on github, NSwag settings should be configured along with MVC settings and this ended up being solution:

```cs
services
  .AddMvc()
  .AddNSwagSettings();
```

Extension method:

```cs
public static IMvcBuilder AddNSwagSettings(this IMvcBuilder builder) =>
  builder.AddJsonOptions(opt =>
    {
      opt.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Add camel case

```
services.AddSwaggerDocument(settings =>
{
  settings.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
  {
      ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
  };
 });
```

Comment: I've just tried this, but seems to me like there's no difference compared to the code without SerializerSettings changed.

Edit: here's an image https://imgur.com/24UW0sA , on the left is previous swagger version - right side is with your code.

Comment: give me nuget url of your swagger version